# Adjusting JS code to Apps Script in Google sheet

Tags: javascript, random, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a working code in JS for my Web Application, which generates custom-format report ID number with the pattern NSAA-####-####-YYYY, where AA - any letter, #### any number, YYYY current year. This function in JS is quoted below.

I was asked to try to transfer the same functionality to Google sheet, as a "custom function."

Although most of the code works fine, I get issues with `indexOf` methods in GAS and overall I am not sure if I am doing it correctly at all.
Would appreciate a quick hint on this.

This is JS code I am trying to reproduce in Apps Script:

```
let d = new Date();
const randomString = (length, chars) => {
  let mask = '';

  if (chars.indexOf('A') > -1) mask += 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  if (chars.indexOf('#') > -1) mask += '0123456789';
  let result = '';
  for (let i = length; i > 0; --i) result += mask[Math.round(Math.random() * (mask.length - 1))];
  return result;
}

// Inserting report ID into appropriate fields
const reportNS = () => {
  let reportIDNS = document.getElementById("reportIDNS");
  reportIDNS.value = 'NS' + randomString(2, 'A') + '-' + randomString(4, '#') + '-' + randomString(4, '#') + '-' +
    d.getFullYear();
}
```

My first idea was to put it in someting like this:

```
/**
 */

var d = new Date();
function randomString (length, chars) {
  var mask = '';

  if (chars.indexOf('A') > -1) mask += 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  if (chars.indexOf('#') > -1) mask += '0123456789';
  var result = '';

  for (var i = length; i > 0; --i)
    result += mask[Math.round(Math.random() * (mask.length - 1))];
  return result = 'NS' + randomString(2, 'A') + '-' + randomString(4, '#') + '-' + randomString(4, '#') + '-' + d.getFullYear();
}
```

However, I get the error

> TypeError: Cannot call method "indexOf" of undefined.

Would appreciate a hint on this!

Comment: If there's a problem, provide [mcve]. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your GAS.

Comment: @TheMaster. It says "TypeError: Cannot call method "indexOf" of undefined."

Comment: You said Custom function. They need to be called from sheet. A1: `=randomString(2,'A')`

Comment: Seems you need to use two functions here - currently each invocation of `randomString` calls `randomString` 3 times. Thus, your "stack depth exceeded" error. Instead you should have `randomString` just return the little random snippet, and a function called from elsewhere that constructs your specific formatted identifier

Comment: @tehhowch - Thank you - of course, I used the second function in the JS code in the same way - solved it below for myself))))!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - here how it works. Of course - need to use the second function to call that randomString:

```
// Funciton to create ReportID (or caseID) as the customer wants
function CaseID () {
  var d = new Date();
  var caseID = 'ID' + randomString(2, 'A') + '-' + randomString(4, '#') + '-' + randomString(4, '#') + '-' + d.getFullYear();
  return caseID;
} 

// Function that generates randomString - no surprises here
function randomString (length, chars) {
  var mask = '';

     if (chars.indexOf('A') > -1) mask += 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
     if (chars.indexOf('#') > -1) mask += '0123456789';
      var result = '';

  for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) {
    result += mask[Math.round(Math.random() * (mask.length - 1))]
  };
      return result;
 }
```